# types typescript inside for loop local loop variable not respecting type

Tags: typescript, types

this.venuelist has type Venue

```
venuelist:Venue[] = [];
```

Type `Venue` has the property `neighborhood` on it.

I have the following for loop

```
for(let venue in this.venuelist){
      let remove = false;
      if(this.filters.neighborhood != ''){
        if(venue.neighborhood != this.filters.neighborhood){
          remove = true;
        }
      }
    }

calling venue.neighborhood called in the second `if statement` is not working
```

the error is: Property 'neighborhood' does not exist on type 'string.

for why? Why must it do this. Why can't it play nice? How do I make it place nice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(let venue in this.venuelist){}
```

for...in doesn't iterate over the array items, it iterates over the keys of the object passed in. You should use `for...of`

Answer (score 0):

```js
for(let venue in this.venuelist){
      let remove = false;
      if(this.filters.neighborhood != ''){
        if(this.venuelist[venue].neighborhood != this.filters.neighborhood){
          remove = true;
        }
      }
    }
```